# Modeling a waiting line in a call centre in AnyLogic

Tags: service, anylogic, modeling

I need to model a waiting line in a call centre in AnyLogic. This is what I don't understand. It says:

> If all of the service representatives are busy, an arriving customer is placed on hold, but ties up on the phone lines.

I am not sure what block or how to model *customers waiting*. Can someone help me? Thank You!

Comment: Are the phone lines a limited resource in your model with greater capacity than the representatives or an unlimited resource where you would just need customers to wait?

Comment: A call center has 24 phone lines and 3 customer service representatives. Suppose
that calls arrive to the center according to a Poisson process with rate λ = 15 per
hour. The time to process each call is exponential with a mean of 10 minutes.
If all of the service representatives are busy, an arriving customer is placed on
hold, but ties up on the phone lines. If all of the phone lines are tied up, the
customer receives a busy signal and the call is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, although I'm absolutely sure other methods exist.

1. To represent an arrival rate of 15/hr, use a source block with arrivals defined by rate, with the rate set to 15 per hour.
   [image: Source block logic]
2. To represent 24 phone lines and 3 service reps, use a queue block (callsWaiting) followed by a delay block (service). The queue block should have capacity = 21 and the delay block should have capacity = 3 with a delay time of exponential(0.1,0) minutes representing the exponential service time (with mean 10 min).
3. To represent losing calls when all of the phone lines are tied up, place a selectOutput block before the callsWaiting queue and set its condition to: callsWaiting.canEnter(). It will return false if the queue is at maximum capacity. On the false branch for that selectOutput, place a sink block for dropped calls.
   [image: Select Output logic]

Comment: Hey Jim, thank you so much!!!
 
However, I am still not sure if this answers my questions for this part - If all of the service representatives are busy, an arriving customer is placed on hold, but ties up on the phone lines.  It's solves more the questions -> If all of the phone lines are tied up, the customer receives a busy signal and the call is lost.

Then, I am asked (a) What is the average time that a customer spends on hold?
(b) What is the average number of lines busy at one time?

Comment: a) the average time a customer spends on hold is equal to the average time it spends inside the callsWaiting queue block. One way to do this is to add a new variable (type double) to your agent and name it "onHoldStartTime". Then, on entering the queue call: agent.onHoldStartTime = time(); and on exiting the queue call: holdTimeData.add(time() - agent.onHoldStartTime ); (where holdTimeData is a DataSet, Histogram Data or statistics object, etc) then the mean is easily accessible from that object.

Comment: b) One method to get the average number of lines busy at one time is to use a cyclic event whose action calculates the number of busy lines and adds it to a dataset (i.e. nLinesBusyData.add(linesBusy)). The total number of lines busy at once is equal to the size of the delay block plus the size of the queue block. Therefore, linesBusy = callsWaiting.size() + service.size().

Comment: See this post for more info and other solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791353/average-number-waiting-and-waiting-time-in-a-queue